# R - convert matrix to one-column table

Tags: r, reshape

I've got matrix like this:

```
    a    b    c
x   1    2    3
y   3    3    2
```

I need to transform it to data.frame like below

```
x a 1 
x b 2 
x c 3 
y a 3 
y b 3 
y c 2
```

I know that split() should work, but I can not set a,b,c as second names of rows.  What should I do?

Comment: You can use melt from reshape2 like this: reshape2::melt(M)
That will get you the output you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `as.data.frame(as.table())`:

```
m <- matrix(c(1,3,2,3,3,2), nrow = 2)
rownames(m) <- c("x", "y")
colnames(m) <- letters[1:3]

  a b c
x 1 2 3
y 3 3 2

as.data.frame(as.table(m))

  Var1 Var2 Freq
1    x    a    1
2    y    a    3
3    x    b    2
4    y    b    3
5    x    c    3
6    y    c    2
```